# How to save download zip to public folder in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, zip, addition, php-ziparchive

I want to download a folder into ZIP format with my code below.

Actually this work perfectly for download folder to zip only.

But i want the zip file also save to public folder in public/folder. 
i use laravel and ziparchive

Please help me

```
 public function downloadzip($id_pra) {
     $dcmt = DB::table('document')->select(DB::raw(" max(id) as id"))->where('id_praapplication',$id_pra)->groupBy('type')->pluck('id');

     $files = Document::whereIn('id', $dcmt)->get(); 

     $url = url('')."/storage/uploads/file/".$id_pra."/"; 

     # create new zip opbject
     $zip = new \ZipArchive();

     # create a temp file & open it
     $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
     $zip->open($tmp_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
     # loop through each file

     foreach($files as $file){
         $url2 = $url.$file->upload;
         $url2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url2);

         if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
             die('CURL is not installed!');
         }

         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $output = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         $download_file = $output;

         $type = substr($url2, -5, 5); 
         #add it to the zip
         $zip->addFromString(basename($url.$file->upload.'.'.$type),$download_file);
     }

     # close zip
     $zip->close();

     # send the file to the browser as a download
     ob_start();
     $strFile = file_get_contents($tmp_file);         
     header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=DOC-'.$id_pra.'-'.$url.'.zip');
     header('Content-type: application/zip');
     echo $tmp_file;
     while (ob_get_level()) {
         ob_end_clean();
     }

     readfile($tmp_file);
     exit;   
}
```

Comment: Can you not just use the `copy`, or `file_put_contents` functions (or others) to additionally write the file to the relevant place then send the file?

Comment: @common sense, oh sorry, something missed in my code, already update for $dcmt

Comment: What is stored inside `$file->upload`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a temp file you can just create the ZIP file directly and later use the Filesystem API to download it.

```
public function downloadzip($id_pra) {
     $dcmt = DB::table('document')->select(DB::raw(" max(id) as id"))->where('id_praapplication',$id_pra)->groupBy('type')->pluck('id');

     $files = Document::whereIn('id', $dcmt)->get(); 

     $url = url('')."/storage/uploads/file/".$id_pra."/"; 

     // create new zip object
     $zip = new \ZipArchive();

     // store the public path
     $publicDir = public_path();

     // Define the file name. Give it a unique name to avoid overriding.
     $zipFileName = 'Documents.zip';

     // Create the ZIP file directly inside the desired folder. No need for a temporary file.
     if ($zip->open($publicDir . '/folder/' . $zipFileName, \ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
         // Loop through each file
         foreach($files as $file){
             $url2 = $url.$file->upload;
             $url2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url2);

             if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
                 die('CURL is not installed!');
             }

             $ch = curl_init();
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
             $output = curl_exec($ch);
             curl_close($ch);
             $download_file = $output;

             $type = substr($url2, -5, 5); 
             #add it to the zip
             $zip->addFromString(basename($url.$file->upload.'.'.$type),$download_file);
         }

         // close zip
         $zip->close();
     }

     // Download the file using the Filesystem API
     $filePath = $publicDir . '/folder/' . $zipFileName;

     if (file_exists($filePath)) {
         return Storage::download($filePath);
     }
}
```

**Note:**

I would extract the CURL part to a method `fetchFile($url);` which returns the downloaded file, but this is out of scope of this question.